# CSS/RegEx: Select elements where a certain attribute contains only numbers at certain locations

Tags: css, regex

I am currently working on a web app and I need to query a data attribute that repeatedly shows up in a table.

In the table that I declare a `data-test-id` attribute that I can use later for testing. One example:

```js
<td data-test-id="table-element-1-9:0-cell"> Hello world!<td>
```

I am querying the data attributes with a css selector for testing. The only thing that changes with each use of the `data-test-id` attribute are the three numbers which I will replace with `X` here:

```css
/* css selector */

.select('[data-test-id="table-element-X-X:X-cell"]')
```

How do I create a regular expression to match all of the other characters is this attribute while ignoring the numbers denoted by `X` (as in the number denoted by X can be any number from 0-9)?

I tried using the following but it doesn't seem to work:

```js
/\[data-test-id="table-element-[0-9]-[0-9]:[0-9]-cell"\]/g
```

Comment: The pattern matches https://regex101.com/r/xGAJVl/1 Note that `[0-9]` will match a single digit 0-9.

Comment: `.select()` to match `td`? This doesn't look like CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well AFAIK there is no regex-matching [attribute selector in CSS](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#attribute-selectors). You could instead use a broader selector of

```css
[data-test-id^="table-element-"][data-test-id$="-cell"]
```

This matches all elements with a `data-test-id` attribute that starts with `table-element-` and ends in `-cell`. Of course that might not be specific enough depending on the possible values of that attribute.

If that is the case, you could further filter the elements that are returned by above query using whatever language you call the `select` function from. For example using the regex you provided above.